# Pull request creation was canceled when having two branches?

Tags: bitbucket

I have two branches in BitBucket server.

```
1. master
2. feature
```

Process is:

`we have to take the latest code from Master. Once our changes or script creation is done. we will push it to feature for review. If review is approved, it will be merged with master for automation purpose`.

First Time,

```
>> git clone "hosturl"
   Make some changes
>> git checkout feature
>> git status
>> git add *
>> git commit -m "test"
>> git push
```

It is getting pushed in to Feature branch.

From Bitbucket UI, I am trying to `CreatePullRequests`

It shows select `source` and `destination`.

I am selecting source as Feature and Destination as Master and entering reviewer mail id. It is working fine.

**`The same case for next time onwards I am getting issues`**

```
>> git checkout master
>> git pull    
Make some changes
>> git checkout feature
>> git status
>> git add *
>> git commit -m "test"
>> git push
```

It is getting pushed in to Feature branch.

From Bitbucket UI, I am trying to `CreatePullRequests`

It shows select `source` and `destination`.

I am selecting source as Feature and Destination as Master and entering reviewer mail id. It is showing

```
`Pull request creation was canceled`.

    •Please rebase your branch on to the target branch before creating a pull request: git checkout feature; git rebase master; git push -f
```

When pulling from master and push to feature we are getting the above error. But when clone from master and push to feature working fine as said (first time).

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your feature branch and master are not in sync. You need to merge the master changes into feature branch.

Try these steps:

```
git checkout master
git pull
<Make changes>>
git add *
git checkout feature
git commit -m "test"
git merge --no-ff origin master
git push
```

Comment: This is working fine for me.. I have encountered one problem after entering   git merge --no-ff origin master..                                             I am getting please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary... and an empty message aborts the commit ...... the bash window does not allow me to enter any comment.. I have close it and reopen that and again if i give                                         git commit and git push is working..                                                     Is this expected procdure..??